# Where can I go to get statistics on iPhone thefts?

Tags: police

I'd like to know how many iPhones have been stolen since Activation Lock was introduced.

Comment: I was going to suggest looking at police records for an individual city and it seems the drop has been noticed: http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/02/11/us-usa-smartphone-killswitch-idUSKBN0LF09520150211?feedType=RSS&feedName=technologyNews

Comment: @philshem Link's broken now.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20161030182600/http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-smartphone-killswitch-idUSKBN0LF09520150211